# how to open zip folder in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, zip

I have a JS, CSS, and HTML files in a zip folder. How could I open it directly in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by simply extracting the JS,CSS and HTML files and placing them in a new non zipped folder. Then opened that new folder in visual studio code.